# libgdx / Android :Can't get my project packed to an .APK file

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, apk, packaging

I'm trying to package my projects so I could test it on my Android device.
The desktop project is working fine in Eclipse and the Android project appears to not have any problems, but I cant's seem to get the project packed to an .APK file, nor package for desktop.

I have no clue of where to start with trying to fix this problem', so any help would be much appreciated.

From the commandline if i try packaging with:

```
gradlew android:assembleRelease --stacktrace
```

[image]

if i run:

```
gradlew tasks debug
```

this is the info i get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/libgdx-anroid-can-t-get-my-project-packed-to-an-apk-file/34034/msg/320661/view/topicseen.html#msg320661

Comment: What is the rubygrapefruit platform? I don't believe that is included in libgdx, is it? It can't load a native library.

Comment: I've got no idea what the rubygrapefruitplatform is... As far as I know it's not something I've added to my project

Comment: How about just launching android app from eclipse?

Comment: As a work around you could try to create a project from scratch and copy your java files over. See if it's still broken then.

Comment: I have tried launching my app using a virtual device within eclipse but so far no luck..
I'm getting a runtimexException error even though my sound files are infact located in the assets/music folder (and within the desktop project they work just fine)


08-06 20:20:37.020: E/AndroidRuntime(814): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading audio file: music/level1.ogg
08-06 20:20:37.020: E/AndroidRuntime(814): Note: Internal audio files must be placed in the assets directory.

Comment: I'll try a work around first thing in the morning, creating a new libgdx project and just see if i can get that packed

Comment: In case you are using Eclipse, you can right-click your project and select the export option. You would have to go through the export wizzard filling some fields, so even though isnt as automatic as making calls from the console it gets the job done if the project is working fine.